# Making a function that constructs a maximal set of distinct hands from a given deck

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to write a function that constructs a maximal set of distinct hands from deck. I made a function allHands that gives all possible 5-card hands that can be taken from a given deck where

```
type Deck = [Card] 

data Card = Card { rank :: Rank, suit :: Suit }
deriving (Eq, Ord)

data Rank = R2 | R3 | R4 | R5 | R6 | R7 | R8 | R9 | R10 | J | Q | K | A
deriving (Bounded, Enum, Eq, Ord)  

data Suit = S | H | D | C --spades , hearts, diamonds, clubs
deriving (Bounded, Enum, Eq, Ord, Show)

newtype Hand = Hand { unHand :: [Card] } deriving (Eq, Show)

distinctHands :: Deck -> Set Hand
distinctHands deck = foldl insert empty (allHands deck)

allHands :: Deck -> [Hand]
allHands deck = map Hand (combs 5 deck)

combs :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
combs 0 [] = [[]]
combs 0 xs = [[]]
combs 1 xs = map (:[]) xs 
combs n xs = [ y: ys | y:xs' <- tails xs, ys <- combs (n-1) xs']
```

When I compile my code in GHCi it gives the following errors:

```
Couldn't match type ‘Set Hand’ with ‘Hand’
   Expected type: Set Hand -> Set Hand -> Set Hand
   Actual type: Hand -> Set Hand -> Set Hand
   In the first argument of ‘foldl’, namely ‘insert’ 

Couldn't match type ‘Hand’ with ‘Set Hand’
   Expected type: [Set Hand]
   Actual type: [Hand]
   In the third argument of ‘foldl’, namely ‘(allHands deck)’
```

I don't know how to fix this can anyone help?

Comment: Include your imports and the definitions of `Deck` and `Hand` so that we can reproduce your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts to reduce the problem to just the relevant core information, that's much appreciated! Unfortunately, even after your latest edit I had to make many changes to produce the problem you report. In the future, please test that your reduction has not removed any important information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`foldl` expects a function with the shape `b -> a -> b`:

```
foldl :: Foldable t => (b -> a -> b) -> b -> t a -> b
```

But `insert` has a flipped shape:

```
insert :: Ord a => a -> Set a -> Set a
```

You can use `flip` to fix the mismatch:

```
flip :: (a -> b -> c) -> (b -> a -> c)
```

Thus, try `distinctHands deck = foldl (flip insert) empty (allHands deck)`. You may also like the `fromList` function

```
fromList :: Ord a => [a] -> Set a
```

which would let you write `distinctHands = fromList . allHands`.

Answer (score 0):

distinctHands :: Deck -> Set Hand
distinctHands deck = foldl' (\set hand -> insert hand set) empty (allHands deck)